# Problems trying to install package in R

Tags: r, nnet

I am having problems trying to install the nnet package in R.  The download seems to be ok, but when I load the library it states

> namespace ‘nnet’ is imported by ‘car’, ‘effects’ so cannot be unloaded
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> package ‘nnet’ was built under R version 3.2.5
>
> Error in library(nnet) : Package ‘nnet’ version 7.3.11 cannot be unloaded

I tried reading other topics which suggest using remove.packages on car and effects. However I tried this and I am still unable to install

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try `unloadNamespace('effects')` before trying `library(nnet)`.

Comment: Although now I have another problem.  I had to uninstall car and sjplot to install this, but now both say

>Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
>lazy-load database '\\[xxx]/My Documents/R/win-library/3.2/car/R/car.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: Also says the same for sjPlot

Comment: This is the error you get when you try to `install.packages('car')`?

Comment: Hi Gaurav.  No this is the error I get when I try library(sjPlot)

Comment: Try removing all affected packages like so: `remove.packages('car')`, and then reinstalling them.