# Getting "lazy load database corrupt" errors in R

Tags: r, nnet, sjplot

I have had some problems with R recently.  I was trying to install nnet which seemed not to be working.  I followed the advice on this question and used remove.packages () and unloadNamespace() on 'car', 'effects' and 'sjPlot'.

[Problems trying to install package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031457/problems-trying-to-install-package-in-r/37032103#37032103)

This was successful in installing nnet, however now im unable to reinstall the three packages.  After reinstalling each package, r states:

> library(sjPlot)
>
> Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
>    lazy-load database '\xxx/SSD_Home_Data_O/xxx/My Documents/R/win-library/3.2/car/R/car.rdb' is corrupt
>
> 2: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
>     restarting interrupted promise evaluation
>
> 3: In get(method, envir = home) :
>     restarting interrupted promise evaluation
>
> 4: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’

Any ideas how to fix this? Im a bit worried as I really need to use sjPlot in particular

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you completely removed and re-installed all affected packages?

Comment: As far as im aware I have yeah.  Do I need to manually go into the folder and delete it?